# Deploy kubeflow on GCP CloudShell using cli: /home/user/.kube/config: no such file or directory

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-shell, kubeflow

I need to deploy Kubeflowfor ML pipeline and TFX on GCP. Unfortunately I cannot use the following UI for the installation, because I need to setup manually, the Zone, Network and Subnet.
[image]

There is a nice documentation page:
https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/gke/deploy/deploy-cli/

I tried with both OAuth credentials and basic authentication. I also tried to install `kfctl_v0.5.1_linux.tar.gz` and `kfctl_v0.5.0_linux.tar.gz`. I always got the following:

```
WARN[0036] could not open /home/user/.kube/config Error stat /home/user/.kube/config: no such file or directory  filename=“apps/group.go:188”
WARN[0036] could not load config Error: open /home/user/.kube/config: no such file or directory  filename=“apps/group.go:208"
```

I have kubectl installed:

```
kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"12+", GitVersion:"v1.12.8-dispatcher", GitCommit:"1215389331387f57594b42c5dd024a2fe27334f8", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-05-1
3T18:09:56Z", GoVersion:"go1.10.8", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

Clearly ~/.kube/config doesn't exist. Which application is suppose to create it ?

```
ls ~/.kube/config
ls: cannot access '/home/user/.kube/config': No such file or directory
```

I did the following:

```
ls home/user/folder/kubeflow
kfctl  kfctl_v0.5.1_linux.tar.gz


export KUBEFLOW_USERNAME=xxx
export KUBEFLOW_PASSWORD=xxx
export PATH=$PATH:/home/user/folder/kubeflow
export ZONE=europe-west1-b
export PROJECT=project
export KFAPP=kubeflow-test
```

from home/user/folder/kubeflow:

```
kfctl init ${KFAPP} --platform gcp --project ${PROJECT} --use_basic_auth -V

INFO[0014] Not skipping GCP project init, running gcpInitProject.  filename="gcp/gcp.go:1619"
WARN[0017] batch API enabling is running: [deploymentmanager.googleapis.com servicemanagement.googleapis.com container.googleapis.com cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com endpoints.googleapis.com file.googleapis.com ml.googleapis.com iam.googleapis.com sqladmin.googleapis.com] (op = operations/acf.954cc3b6-f1f4-46a2-832d-596ccb5a3d5a)  filename="gcp/gcp.go:1594"
WARN[0018] batch API enabling is running: [deploymentmanager.googleapis.com servicemanagement.googleapis.com container.googleapis.com cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com endpoints.googleapis.com file.googleapis.com ml.googleapis.com iam.googleapis.com sqladmin.googleapis.com] (op = operations/acf.954cc3b6-f1f4-46a2-832d-596ccb5a3d5a)  filename="gcp/gcp.go:1594"
WARN[0019] batch API enabling is running: [deploymentmanager.googleapis.com servicemanagement.googleapis.com container.googleapis.com cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com endpoints.googleapis.com file.googleapis.com ml.googleapis.com iam.googleapis.com sqladmin.googleapis.com] (op = operations/acf.954cc3b6-f1f4-46a2-832d-596ccb5a3d5a)  filename="gcp/gcp.go:1594"
WARN[0021] batch API enabling is running: [deploymentmanager.googleapis.com servicemanagement.googleapis.com container.googleapis.com cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com endpoints.googleapis.com file.googleapis.com ml.googleapis.com iam.googleapis.com sqladmin.googleapis.com] (op = operations/acf.954cc3b6-f1f4-46a2-832d-596ccb5a3d5a)  filename="gcp/gcp.go:1594"
WARN[0024] batch API enabling is running: [deploymentmanager.googleapis.com servicemanagement.googleapis.com container.googleapis.com cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com endpoints.googleapis.com file.googleapis.com ml.googleapis.com iam.googleapis.com sqladmin.googleapis.com] (op = operations/acf.954cc3b6-f1f4-46a2-832d-596ccb5a3d5a)  filename="gcp/gcp.go:1594"
WARN[0027] batch API enabling is running: [deploymentmanager.googleapis.com servicemanagement.googleapis.com container.googleapis.com cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com endpoints.googleapis.com file.googleapis.com ml.googleapis.com iam.googleapis.com sqladmin.googleapis.com] (op = operations/acf.954cc3b6-f1f4-46a2-832d-596ccb5a3d5a)  filename="gcp/gcp.go:1594"
WARN[0030] batch API enabling is running: [deploymentmanager.googleapis.com servicemanagement.googleapis.com container.googleapis.com cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com endpoints.googleapis.com file.googleapis.com ml.googleapis.com iam.googleapis.com sqladmin.googleapis.com] (op = operations/acf.954cc3b6-f1f4-46a2-832d-596ccb5a3d5a)  filename="gcp/gcp.go:1594"
INFO[0037] batch API enabling is completed: [deploymentmanager.googleapis.com servicemanagement.googleapis.com container.googleapis.com cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com endpoints.googleapis.com file.googleapis.com ml.googleapis.com iam.googleapis.com sqladmin.googleapis.com]  filename="gcp/gcp.go:1590"
INFO[0037] reading from /home/user/folder/kubeflow/kubeflow-test/app.yaml  filename="coordinator/coordinator.go:341"
WARN[0037] could not open /home/user/.kube/config Error stat /home/user/.kube/config: no such file or directory  filename="apps/group.go:188"
WARN[0037] could not load config Error: open /home/user/.kube/config: no such file or directory  filename="apps/group.go:208"
```

Some file were created:

```
ls kubeflow-test/
app.yaml
```

Some check:

```
kubectl config view
apiVersion: v1
clusters: []
contexts: []
current-context: ""
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users: []
```

I also try to update  kubectl

```
gcloud components update kubectl
You have specified individual components to update.  If you are trying
 to install new components, use:
  $ gcloud components install kubectl
Do you want to run install instead (y/N)?  y
All components are up to date.
```

Any idea why I don't have `~/.kube/config` doesn't exist ? I try to create it manually but then I have other issue later. What should I do to create the mising configuration. Is there another recommend way than using CloudShell to deploy Kubelow with cli on GCP ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GKE has a great [description of how you can configure access to a cluster via kubectl](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/cluster-access-for-kubectl) (which uses the `~/.kube/config` file as the default location to store credentials). There are two ways to populate the file:

1. Create your cluster through the command line using `gcloud container clusters create CLUSTER_NAME`
2. Fetching credentials for an existing cluster using `gcloud container clusters get-credentials CLUSTER_NAME`

From the Kubeflow docs, it looks like the init step doesn't create a cluster; the apply step should create a cluster. You don't describe what issue you have later if you create an empty file.

Also, you pointed to the deploy cli docs, but the [customizing Kubeflow on GKE](https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/gke/customizing-gke/) page sounds more like what you are trying to accomplish so you might see if that page answers any of your questions.

Comment: Great, this solve my issue. Thanks.  Concerning the docs you mentioned, the deploy cli page is almost the first step. First you need to setup a GCP project and then create an OAuth client.